# Правильное употребление нормы

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, как правильно употреблять выражение согласно нормам русского литературного языка: "возвращаться из хаджа" или "возвращаться с хаджа"?

Answer (score 2):

**Из** хаджа, поскольку это разновидность паломничества, путешествия (совершить путешествие - отправиться **в** путешествие - вернуться **из** путешествия).

**P.S.** Противоположный случай в отношении предлогов: "**на** шабаш" (ведьм и пр.) и "**с** шабаша" - здесь смысл мероприятия - в обрядах по прибытии на место назначения, а не в дальней дороге ради посещения святого места, как в случае хаджа.

Answer (score 2):

1) **Глаголы вернуться/возвратится могут сочетаться с предлогами С и ИЗ**: из путешествия, из отпуска, с прогулки, с работы.

2) **Реально встречаются обе формы:** возвращаться из хаджа / с хаджа, сочетание неустоявшееся. Здесь важна традиция  употребления предлога, также надо оценивать частотность употребления сочетания.

3) **С точки зрения русской грамматики, предлог ИЗ является более подходящим**. Хадж - это **особенным образом организованное паломничество** (согласно учению ислама, хадж должен совершить хотя бы один раз в жизни каждый мусульманин, который в состоянии это сделать). Поэтому выбор "из предмета / с предмета" должен быть сделан в пользу предлог ИЗ.

**Примеры**

Он мог даровать деньги на авиабилеты нищим индонезийским паломникам, обобранным проводником на обратном пути **с хаджа.** [Александр Иличевский. Перс (2009)]

Приближаются дни возвращения наших паломников **с хаджа** домой, на родину, к своим семьям.

Паломники возвращаются **из хаджа**.

Многие верующие по возвращении **из хаджа** задаются вопросом о том, что им необходимо изменить в своей жизни после совершения паломничества.

Comment: В последнем примере - ошибка (надо "по возвращени**и**"). Что касается частотности вариантов с альтернативным предлогом, то гугл, хотя и не трактует предложенное как явную ошибку, "молча" приводит результаты с предлогом "из". Видимо, сложившаяся практика подтверждает, что суть "подвига" (в христианском понимании) при хадже состоит в _труде преодоления расстояния_ ради посещения святого места, в самом путешествии, а не в обряде по прибытии на место. Находясь в пути, паломник уже совершает хадж. По этой же причине не говорят "на поход" и "с похода".

Comment: Я не об этом, дело не в частных особенностях, а в структуре "предмета". Если она сложная, то предмет представляется объемным, имеющим ВНУТРЕННЕЕ содержание, поэтому желателен предлог ИЗ. Это именно путешествие, а не прогулка.

Answer (score 0):

Дополню предыдущий ответ пояснением: "возвращаться с хаджа" звучит так же некорректно, как и распространенное "с какого ты района", и предлог "с" здесь абсолютно не уместен. Сопоставление с "из путешествия" или "из поездки" представляется вполне верным.

Answer (score 0):

"Согласно нормам русского литературного языка" можно употреблять **оба** предлога, так как хадж - это особое паломничество, **не только путешествие, но и обряд,** вернее ряд обрядов (главный обряд хаджа — предстояние перед ликом Аллаха).

В  терминологическом значении Шариата хадж означает  **специальное действие, совершаемое в определённое время, в определённом месте и определённым образом, один из видов джихада, обряд поклонения**. Просто путешествие по святым местам не хадж. Главное -особое состояние духовной чистоты ихра́м (араб. إحرام‎ — посвящение). 
В этом состоянии запрещается заниматься торговлей и делами, относящимся к мирской жизни;свататься или вступать в брак; гневаться и обижать кого-либо; убивать животных и насекомых, рвать траву и срывать листья и ветки с деревьев и т. д.; бриться, стричь волосы и ногти, использовать благовония, надевать украшения и курить.

Если Вы хотите сказать, что вернулись из паломничества как путешествия по святым местам,то возвратились **ИЗ** хаджа, если хотите сказать, что вернулись с обряда поклонения, то **С** хаджа